# Limiting array tasks per node in SLURM

Tags: concurrency, task, slurm

Is there any way in SLURM to limit the amount of concurrent array tasks running on a compute node?
I have a user launching 1000 tasks in an array job. When they are launched in the cluster they are distributed among nodes, trying to fill them if possible. But for some reason each array task wants to open a huge amount of files. In the end only 10 of the possible 128 array tasks that can get on the node, do not fail because they consume all available open files per job.

I would like to suggest the user to launch the script but limiting concurrent array tasks on a node. Note that using: --array=0-1000%10 won't do it as it will be calculating just with 10 simultaneous array tasks over the whole cluster. I want to achieve using several nodes each one limited to 10 simultaneous array tasks.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a custom [GRES](https://slurm.schedmd.com/gres.html) tracking the maximum possible number of files to open, and ask the user to request that GRES.

In `slurm.conf`:

```
GresType=openfiles
[...]
Nodename=node[001-003] ... Gres=openfiles:1024
```

In the job script:

```
#SBATCH --gres=openfiles:100
```

That way, only 10 such jobs can possibly land on the same node.